# Magento2 Plugin with Proxy

Tags: magento2, code-generation

In my test extension I try create plugin for 
Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::isRegionRequired method.
My frontend/di.xml contain:

```
<type name="Magento\Directory\Helper\Data">
    <plugin name="Sample_Test::isRegionRequired" type="Sample\Test\Plugin\Country\DirectoryHelperAfter" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

And class Sample\Test\Plugin\Country\DirectoryHelperAfter contain

```
public function afterIsRegionRequired($subject, $result)
{
    exit('test');
    $myResult = true;
    return $myResult;
}
```

On the front I get next error on generating my plugin (before call plugin method):

```
Source class "\DirectoryHelperData" for "DirectoryHelperDataProxy" generation does not exist.
```

In /app/code/Magento/Directory/etc/di.xml I found:

```
<virtualType name="DirectoryHelperDataProxy" type="Magento\Directory\Helper\Data\Proxy">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Directory\Helper\Data</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection" shared="false">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="helperData" xsi:type="object">DirectoryHelperDataProxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

My question is "How I can use plugin for class if it used in proxy"?

Answer (score 3):

From https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html:

> #### Limitations
>
> Plugins cannot be used with any of the following:
>
> - Final methods
> - Final classes
> - Any class that contains at least one final public method
> - Non-public methods
> - Class methods (such as static methods)
> - `__construct`
> - Virtual types

As this is Virtual type, **you can't use plugin for `Magento\Directory\Helper\Data`**
I have encountered the same problem, the best solution I have found is to use `preference`.

```
<preference for="Magento\Directory\Helper\Data" type="Sample\Test\Helper\Data" />
```

It works **as override** of methods.

Comment: Thank for the answer. It is safe to rewrite a class for which there is the virtual type?..

Comment: @sergei.sss Yes, It is a good solution if you can't use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> **How I can use plugin for class if it used in proxy** ?

The plugin (before, after and around ) will work same even the class is used by proxy.

Let us have a quick working example.. [taken](https://github.com/astorm/magento2-tutorial-proxy-objects)

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\Example">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="slow" xsi:type="object">Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\SlowLoading\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\SlowLoading">
        <plugin name="pulsestorm_tutorial_plugin_model_example_plugin"
                type="Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\Example\SlowLoading\Plugin"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

The above di.xml, as we know we are using proxy class for Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\SlowLoading and same class is used by plugin. so inside my Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\Example\SlowLoading\Plugin

```
namespace Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\Example\SlowLoading;

class Plugin
{
    public function afterHello()
    {
        echo "ABCD EFGH";

    }  


}
```

This afterHello method is working fine even the class is using proxy ....:)

Comment: Thank. In Alan's example we see: Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\SlowLoading\Proxy use for plugin as Pulsestorm\TutorialProxy1\Model\SlowLoading (without Proxy). But magento describe proxy as "DirectoryHelperDataProxy". If I use "DirectoryHelperData" the error disappears, but the code execution doesn't reach my plugin.