# Magento 2: virtual types plugins

Tags: magento2, plugin, magento-2.1, virtualtype

I'm confused by [Magento 2 documentation regarding plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html):

[image]

It is first said that:

> Plugins cannot be used with virtual types

But then it is said that:

> You can specify a class, interface, or **virtual type** as a type name
>   which the plugin observes

**Am I missing something or is the documentation contradicting itself ? Can we create plugins for virtual types ?**

Comment: Could you, please, tell me whether you’ve found the right solution or not? You haven’t marked any of the replies as “correct”.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau yeah I tend to forget to mark answers as correct. Both answers are correct. Kandy is a Magento 2 developer so check his answer ;)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111577/magento2-plugin-with-proxy   Is there any way to override this class using plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugins will work for virtual type but only if you specify it for parent classes or interfaces, but you cannot specify plugin specific for concrete virtual type

Comment: So we agree that the doc is not right as it says to explicitely specify the virtual type.

Comment: To be honest, plugins on virtual types worked before developer beta and we have bug to fix it.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111577/magento2-plugin-with-proxy   Is there any way to override this class using plugin.

Answer (score 13):

No, plugins on virtual types do not work.

Proof of concept code:

```
<?php

namespace Training\Example\Model

class Type
{
    public function bar()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

Plugin using `<type>`:

```
<?php

namespace Training\Example\Model;

class TypePlugin
{
    public function afterBar(Type $subject)
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

Plugin using `<virtualType>`:

```
<?php

namespace Training\Example\Model;

class VirtualTypePlugin
{
    public function afterBar(Type $subject)
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

DI config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Foo" type="Training\Example\Model\Type">
        <plugin name="myfoo" type="Training\Example\Model\VirtualTypePlugin"/>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Foo">
        <plugin name="yourfoo" type="Training\Example\Model\TypePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Test:

```
    <?php

namespace Training\Example\Training\Integration;

use Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager;
use Training\Example\Model\Type;
use Training\Example\Model\VirtualTypePlugin;

class VirtualTypePluginTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPluginsOnVirtualTypesWork()
    {
        /** @var Type $instance */
        $instance = ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(Type::class);
        $this->assertSame(VirtualTypePlugin::class, $instance->bar());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
Expected :Training\Example\Model\VirtualTypePlugin
Actual   :Training\Example\Model\Type
```

Comment: I would assume `di.xml` declaration tag would be `type` instead of `virtualType` according to the doc #totrustornottotrustthedoc

Comment: Updated the answer to include a `type` and `virtualType` plugin.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111577/magento2-plugin-with-proxy   Is there any way to override this class using plugin.

Comment: You could intercept the concrete type the virtual type maps to, or alternatively overwrite the virtual type mapping to map to your own class, in effect giving you a kind of class override.