# Magento 2 - Plugin issue in catalogsearch

Tags: magento-2.1, catalogsearch, plugin

I've created a plugin to override `getProductPrice()` method of `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` class.
This is my **app/code/vendorName/moduleName/etc/di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="vendorName_moduleName_Plugin" type="vendorName\moduleName\Plugin\MyPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and this plugin class (**app/code/vendorName/moduleName/Plugin/MyPlugin.php**):

```
<?php

namespace vendorName\moduleName\Plugin;

class MyPlugin
{
    public function afterGetProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $product, $result)
    {
        return $result.'<input type="hidden" class="my-class" />';
    }
}
```

It works fine when a category page is called but it doesn't override methods when I try to search a product.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @fschmengler and reading [Magento 2: virtual types plugins](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123366/magento-2-virtual-types-plugins) I solved using this **app/code/vendorName/moduleName/etc/di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="vendorName_moduleName_Plugin" type="vendorName\moduleName\Plugin\MyPlugin" />
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="vendorName_moduleName_VirtualPlugin"
                type="vendorName\moduleName\Plugin\MyPlugin" />
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Comment: OK, then this probably has changed in 2.1, glad that you figured it out!

Comment: In effect, I'm using 2.1.2
In any case, it's so strange.. **type** attribute in _<virtualType>_ element is mandatory but it takes "parent" Plugin so you could write everything in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another plugin for it

**app/code/vendorName/moduleName/etc/di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="vendorName_moduleName_Plugin" type="vendorName\moduleName\Plugin\MyPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Your plugin file at **app/code/vendorName/moduleName/Plugin/MyPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace vendorName\moduleName\Plugin;

class MyPlugin
{
    public function afterGetProductPrice(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct $product, $result)
    {
        return $result.'<input type="hidden" class="my-class" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: But `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct` class doesn't exist.

Comment: If you go to layout of `catalogsearch_result_index`  you will find `<block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="product/list.phtml" cacheable="false">`

Comment: Ok but has it got `getProductPrice()` method?

If I follow your advice, I receive this error message: ***Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Source class "\Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" for "Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct\Interceptor" generation does not exist.***

Comment: In any case, I'm trying to debug and when search result page is loaded, it calls `getProductPrice()` method of `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` class but **Plugin** is not able to override it. It's so strange..

Comment: `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct` is a virtual type and the actual class is `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` (see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1ade3b769a937f19682bbbe4e51b6c956147952f/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/frontend/di.xml#L19) - so the plugin should work. See: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123366/magento-2-virtual-types-plugins

Comment: Thus should it work? But using my di.xml declaration or have I to change something in it?
Actually it does not work.. you can try, I could pass you my code.