# interceptor not generate for \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

Tags: magento2, override-block, interceptor

I'm trying to create plugin for `getProductPrice` but `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` Block Class not generate Interceptor Class like `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor`.

My di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="addSimplePriceUnit" type="MagArs\PriceUnit\Plugin\Product\Simple"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

My plugin Class

```
namespace MagArs\PriceUnit\Plugin\Product;
    class Simple {
        public function beforeGetProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject, $result){
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

moduel.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MagArs_PriceUnit" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

I am using magento enterprise version 2.2.5

Comment: Can you please add your di.xml and plugin code here

Comment: @RutveeSojitra i update my question please look into my question.

Comment: Please share the full code of your plugin class and module.xml as well

Comment: @RutveeSojitra i update my question.

Comment: You want to get specific product price in plugin ?

Comment: I just return price block html and add additional html for this block.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if still question not solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this by using virtual types plugins.

I just add in my di.xml file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="addSimplePriceUnit" type="MagArs\PriceUnit\Plugin\Product\Simple" />
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="addSimplePriceUnitVirtualPlugin"
                type="MagArs\PriceUnit\Plugin\Product\Simple" />
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

and plugin class here

```
class Simple extends AbstractPriceUnit {
    public function afterGetProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $product, $result){
        return $result."<h2>some html</h2>";
    }
}
```

I found the solution from the following [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150934/magento-2-plugin-issue-in-catalogsearch)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, this helped me  a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing your code with:

```
class Simple {
     public function 
    beforeGetProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product){
          //you have to add your logic
      }
        }
```

Check after running below this commands:

```
rm -rf generated/*

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: you just add  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product in parameters and return the $result which make no sense. can you please elaborate this.

Comment: I have edited @ArshadMuhammad please check what you want to add custom logic which you have to add in method

Comment: And add in question if you are facing any error

Comment: I am just updating my version 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 let see what happens

Comment: not working with 2.2.6. Did you test this your self.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue you just need to delete generated folder and then check.

If the cache is enabled then you need to refresh cache using

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Update your **di.xml** with this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type  name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
       <plugin name="addSimplePriceUnit" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" type="MagArs\PriceUnit\Plugin\Product\Simple"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin `MagArs\PriceUnit\Plugin\Product\Simple.php`

```
<?php

namespace MagArs\PriceUnit\Plugin\Product;

class Simple
{
    public function beforeGetProductPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return $result;
    }

}
```

After this you can check your productlist page.

Comment: did you test the code see the generated interceptor class. I did refresh cache and di compile but no luck

Comment: Did you remove generated folder?

Comment: yes i remove generated folder. I am using 2.2.5 version

Comment: did you test this code your self.